# chat web app: flex-boxes inside div position:fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a chat web app with a bottom bar consisting of: button, text entry, button:

```
<div id="bottom-bar">
  <div class="button-left">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
  <div class="textentry">
    <input type="text" id="chatmsg" name="chatmsg">
  </div>
  <div class="button-right">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
</div>

#bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I want to achieve: (1) place the left button to the left of the bottom-bar, (2) place the right button to the right of the bottom-bar and (3) have an input field that stretches in the middle using all the space that is available.

I tried:

```css
#bottom-bar {
   ...the css above and additionally ...
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content:space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

#chatmsg{
  width: auto;
}
```

But this got me nowhere. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the textentry has to grow and take all the place left:

```css
#bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.button-left,
.button-right {
  width: 40px;
}
.textentry{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#chatmsg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

check this: https://jsfiddle.net/43Lqzznt/3/

Comment: i think it's better to use snippet code here than jsfiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc(100% - 80px);` as the width for `.textentry` (i.e. full width minus the width of the two images) and make the input 100% wide inside of that. If you do just that, the input overflows its container to the right, so use `padding` on `.textentry` to compensate that and adjust the distance between the elements as desired, as shown in my snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.textentry {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  padding: 0 10px 0 2px;
}

input#chatmsg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom-bar">
  <div class="button-left">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
  <div class="textentry"><input type="text" id="chatmsg" name="chatmsg"></div>
  <div class="button-right">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `display:flex` on the container and by adjusting the input div's `flex:1` or setting it's width to `100%` should do it. Check output in the console.

[**FLEX**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The input box will stretch between the images as the container div shrinks or expands in size.

```css
#bottom-bar {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content:space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

#chatmsg{
  width: 100%;
}

.textentry {
  /* width: 100% */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom-bar">
  <div class="button-left">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
  <div class="textentry">
    <input type="text" id="chatmsg" name="chatmsg">
  </div>
  <div class="button-right">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/40x40">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tihnk 100% width on textentry is not appropriate (even if it give the correct visual because of the nowrap) .. you need to use flex:1 instead which is more correct as it means take the remaining space

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's a nice tip! Added it to the answer. Thanks.